# Autohotkey and DCS A-10C flight sim

Tags: autohotkey

I've set up Autohotkey to start DCS A-10C but when starting, it throws an error that it can't open `.\MissionEditor\MissionEditor.lua`

Autohotkey

```
Run, "D:\GAMES\Eagle Dynamics\DCS A-10C\bin\Launcher.exe"
```

If I start the program using the desktop icon it works fine.

Comment: The run command has also a working dir option, so what if you try ```Run, "D:\GAMES\Eagle Dynamics\DCS A-10C\bin\Launcher.exe", "D:\GAMES\Eagle Dynamics\DCS A-10C\bin\"``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `.\` at the beginning of the path in the error message, it appears that the Flight Simulator executable is using relative paths to locate supporting files.

If you right-click on desktop icon and choose `Properties` then go to the `Shortcut` tab, the `Start in:` textbox will display the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) that the desktop icon will launch the program with. The example below launches `cmd.exe` with a working directory of `C:\wamp\www`

[image: Shortcut Properties Window]

Most likely this is `D:\GAMES\Eagle Dynamics\DCS A-10C\bin`. The executable would take it's working directory and append the supporting file it is trying to locate like below:

```
D:\GAMES\Eagle Dynamics\DCS A-10C\bin\MissionEditor\MissionEditor.lua
```

However, the `Run` command in AutoHotKey, by default, will use its (the script's) current directory as the working directory. If for example your script was located in `C:\AutoHotKeyScripts\Launch.ahk`, this would cause the executable to try to locate this file instead:

```
C:\AutoHotKeyScripts\MissionEditor\MissionEditor.lua
```

To manually specify a working directory, place it after the executable name like this:

```
Run, "D:\GAMES\Eagle Dynamics\DCS A-10C\bin\Launcher.exe", "D:\GAMES\Eagle Dynamics\DCS A-10C\bin"
```

Read the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) on the `Run` command for more information.